# How to redirect user to a page with different subdomain after sign_in/sign_out devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, localhost, subdomain, apartment-gem

I have a problem with redirecting to subdomain after devise sign_in or sign_out. I generated devise controllers uncommented methods that should take me where I want but subdomains don't work.

```
    def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
      root_url(subdomain: resource.subdomain)
    end

    def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
      home_url(subdomain: "www")
    end
```

After sign_in I receive an error

> Unsafe redirect to "http://chris.lvh.me:3000/", pass allow_other_host: true to redirect anyway.

So I modified methods in couple ways but it gave me more errors, example of what I've tried:

```
root_url(subdomain: resource.subdomain), allow_other_hosts: true
root_url(subdomain: resource.subdomain, allow_other_hosts: true)
redirect_to root_url(subdomain: resource.subdomain),allow_other_hosts: true
redirect_to root_url(subdomain: resource.subdomain, allow_other_hosts: true)
```

And errors for that were: wrong amount of arguments or unexpected ', ' expected end or something.
After sign_out it takes me to sign_in page and not to home_url and subdomain doesn't change.

I'm using devise, rails-on-services/apartment and rails 7

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The method name is [allow_other_host](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.0.2.2/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html#method-i-redirect_back) without a `s`.

Besides that, you are correct that you should pass it as an argument to `redirect_to`

```rb
redirect_to(root_url, allow_other_host: true)
```

The method `request.subdomain` will use the current URL to determine the subdomain. If you like to redirect to a subdomain, different from the current URL, you can specify it.

```rb
redirect_to(root_url(subdomain: "chris", allow_other_host: true)
# "http://chris.lvh.me:3000/"
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what I've been looking for:)